# How to disable the submit button outside the form

Tags: angularjs

I got a form with two tabs where user should enter the required fields in both the tabs.If I place the submit button inside the form it gets enabled after the first tab details are entered but it should not be highlighted until the second tab details are entered too.
  If I place the button outside the form validations are not working.
  Any suggestions?

Comment: Please add your code, unless we can't help. Also no screenshots -- just copy paste in here. Intend the whole code by 4 spaces. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one, hope this can help:

`<form name="yourForm" ng-submit="submitForm(yourForm.$valid)" novalidate>
    /* Your inputs (say in two tabs) along with their validation */
    <button type="submit" ng-disabled="yourForm.$invalid">Submit</button>
</form>`

This will make your submit button disabled until all your input fields are valid

Comment: Anoop I only have one common submit button for both the tabs.

Comment: Updated please check, and make two tabs inside a  form

Answer (score 0):

If I understand it correctly, you just need a validation check for both inputs, where if they both filled in you can press the submit button. The code should be straight forward if that's the case:

```
<form ng-submit="submit()" name="formName">
  <input name="inputName" ng-model="myInput" required>
  <input name="inputName2" ng-model="myInput2" required>
  <button ng-disabled="!(formName.inputName.$valid && formName.inputName2.$valid)">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: If all the fields are in the same form then I can follow your approach where as few of my fields are in a different tab and a common submit button for both the tabs. So when I enter the fields of first tab then the submit button gets highlighted which should not be the case. Submit button should be in disabled state until I enter all the required fields for both the tabs.

Comment: @sita I don't know what your tabs look like, but you can do nested forms that contain other forms / tabs (?) : `<form name="myForm"><div ng-form="firstNestedForm">...`